# Работа с функциями , переход между способами

Tags: c++, функции

Все необходимые данные для
функций должны передаваться в качестве параметров. Результат функции получить тремя способами: через механизм return, через параметр-указатель, через
ссылочный параметр.
Само задание - Определить, для какого наибольшего n можно вычислить значение (2n)!!
(произведение всех четных натуральных чисел, не превышающих 2n), пользуясь
типом int.
Я только начинаю свой путь в программировании и не смог найти внятные примеры перехода от одного способа к другому . Я написал через механизм return, но остальные два способа у меня не получаются (постоянно компилятор жалуется на разный тип используемых переменных). Не могли бы вы мне помочь с этой простой , но очень важной для меня на данном этапе теме .
Сам код ( через первый способ) :

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;

int lol(int n)
{
   double p=1;
   int j=0;
 
   for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
   {
      if((n%2==0) && (j%2==0))
      {
      p=p*j;

      }
      
      if((n%2!=0)  && (j%2!=0))
      {
      p=p*j;
      }
    }
   return p;
}
 
int main ()
 
{
    int n;
        cout << "N: " << " " ;
        cin >> n;
        if(lol(2*n)>127)
        {
            cout << "Sorry , but no."<< endl;
        }
        else
        cout << "Everything is fine." << endl;
 
}
```

Comment: *"остальные два способа у меня не получаются (постоянно компилятор жалуется"* Покажите код, и точный текст ошибки.

Comment: Странно,  если я задание правильно понял, то функции не нужны никакие аргументы

Comment: Извините за столь долгое ожидание

Comment: https://ideone.com/SeSvFa

Comment: prog.cpp: In function ‘int lol(int, int*)’:
prog.cpp:13:20: error: invalid operands of types ‘int*’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator*’
             *p = p * j;
                  ~~^~~
prog.cpp:19:20: error: invalid operands of types ‘int*’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator*’
             *p = p * j;
                  ~~^~~
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:31:15: error: invalid operands of types ‘int’ and ‘int*’ to binary ‘operator*’
     if (lol(2 * &n) > 127)
             ~~^~~~

Comment: @HolyBlackCat /

Comment: @ARHovsepyan ///

Answer (score 1):

Делать - так делать обобщенно :)

```
template<std::integral T>
T maxBiFact()
{
    T M = std::numeric_limits<T>::max(), F = 1;
    for(T n = 2; ; n += 2)
    {
        if (M/n >= F) F *= n; else return n-2;
    }
}

template<std::integral T>
void maxBiFact(T*t)
{
    if (t) *t = maxBiFact<T>();
}

template<std::integral T>
void maxBiFact(T&t)
{
    t = maxBiFact<T>();
}


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    std::cout << maxBiFact<int>() << std::endl;
    int n;
    maxBiFact(n);
    std::cout << n << std::endl;
    maxBiFact(&n);
    std::cout << n << std::endl;
}
```